# Nesting Navigators: top tab navigator that points to the same screens but different props

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to make an app that has a series of nested navigators. The main navigator is a stack navigator that goes to jobs, job details, and chats. Within the jobs page, there is a top tab navigator that shows open jobs, almost due jobs, and completed jobs. There is also a bottom tab that has jobs (same page), add, and profile. So the jobs page is the home page. Each job entry can be clicked and it will go to the job details . I'm having trouble figuring how to nest and logic these.

- Stack (Main)
- Job Details
- Chat
- Jobs (Top tab Navigator)

  - Open

    - On Press to job details and other pages
  - Almost due

    - On Press to to job details and other pages
  - Done

    - On Press to to job details and other pages
- Jobs (Bottom tab)

  - Jobs
  - Add
  - Profile

So far, I feel like the top navigator will point to the same jobs page but with different params, and the main bottom tab navigator will point to a stack navigator that includes the top tab navigator. But I'm not sure if that is good, and it gets messy. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer without knowing what you want to achieve, but if I wanted to develop an app with those navigators, I will try to keep it as simplified as I can

1. Stack (Main)
2. Job Details
3. Chat
4. Jobs (Bottom Tab Navigator)

   - Add
   - Profile
   - Jobs (Top Tab Navigator)

     - Open  ->  onPress navigate to job details
     - Almost Due  ->  onPress navigate to job details
     - Done ->  onPress navigate to job details

I would further point out that [Each screen in a navigator has its own params](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#each-screen-in-a-navigator-has-its-own-params)

Further, when you navigate a screen in the nested navigator, the specified screen is used as the initial screen and the initial route prop on the navigator is ignored, which I think you were pointing out. you can disable the behaviour of using the specified screen as the initial screen by setting `initial: false`

You can further read about this [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#rendering-initial-route-defined-in-the-navigator).

I would also strongly recommend going through the Navigation Docs for [Nesting Navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators)

Comment: why do we do onpress for the top tab navigator if we specify the screen for each tab?